# The Java BigDecimal vs The Financial Mans - "The 1 cent problem"

Tags: java, bigdecimal

I have this problem: **The financial mans says: "Error of your programation"**.

The official table of values and final calc from financial is

```
base        %              total value
667.63   -  1.5(0.015)   = 657.62
705.98   -  1.5(0.015)   = 695.39
687.77   -  1.5(0.015)   = 677.45
844.62   -  1.5(0.015)   = 831.95
743.23   -  1.5(0.015)   = 732.08
775.15   -  1.5(0.015)   = 763.52
874.82   -  1.5(0.015)   = 861.70
949.63   -  1.5(0.015)   = 935.39
987.18   -  1.5(0.015)   = 972.37
1040.28  -  1.5(0.015)   = 1024.68
1077.70  -  1.5(0.015)   = 1061.54
995.68   -  1.5(0.015)   = 980.74
1280.55  -  1.5(0.015)   = 1261.35
1140.56  -  1.5(0.015)   = 1123.45
653.23   -  1.5(0.015)   = 643.43
847.49   -  1.5(0.015)   = 834.78
995.68   -  1.5(0.015)   = 980.74
```

My function's return value must match the total value from that table:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    BigDecimal[] valorbase= {
        new BigDecimal("667.63"),
        new BigDecimal("705.98"),
        new BigDecimal("687.77"),
        new BigDecimal("844.62"),
        new BigDecimal("743.23"),
        new BigDecimal("775.15"),
        new BigDecimal("874.82"),
        new BigDecimal("949.63"),
        new BigDecimal("987.18"),
        new BigDecimal("1040.28"),
        new BigDecimal("1077.70"),
        new BigDecimal("995.68"),
        new BigDecimal("1280.55"),
        new BigDecimal("1140.56"),
        new BigDecimal("653.23"),
        new BigDecimal("847.49"),
        new BigDecimal("995.68")    
    };

    for (int i = 0; i < valorbase.length; i++) {
        BigDecimal desconto=new BigDecimal("0.015");
        BigDecimal valor_a_descontar=valorbase[i].multiply(desconto);

            valor_a_descontar=valor_a_descontar.setScale(2,RoundingMode.HALF_UP);
    //desconto=desconto.setScale(2,RoundingMode.HALF_UP);


    BigDecimal valortotal=valorbase[i].subtract(valor_a_descontar);
    valortotal.setScale(3,RoundingMode.HALF_UP);
    valortotal.setScale(2,RoundingMode.HALF_UP);

        System.out.println("BASE=" + valorbase[i] + " - descount=" + valor_a_descontar + " totalvalue=" + valortotal);
    }
}
```

system out: 

`BASE=1077.70 - descount=16.17 totalvalue=1061.53 missing value of table!
BASE=1280.55 - descount=19.21 totalvalue=1261.34 missing value of table!`

The diff in some case is 0,01 cent but to financial it's impossible becouse this universe of people is 18.340 registry's the diff is 18340 x 0.01 x 365 x 2 = 4401,6 ===> R$ 4401,6 this the cost of one cent not rounded correctly! Can anyone help me? 
thanks JAY...
This was proposed by JAY:

```
public static void main(String[] args){
    BigDecimal[] valorbase= {
            new BigDecimal("667.63"),
            new BigDecimal("705.98"),
            new BigDecimal("687.77"),
            new BigDecimal("844.62"),
            new BigDecimal("743.23"),
            new BigDecimal("775.15"),
            new BigDecimal("874.82"),
            new BigDecimal("949.63"),
            new BigDecimal("987.18"),
            new BigDecimal("1040.28"),
            new BigDecimal("1077.70"),
            new BigDecimal("995.68"),
            new BigDecimal("1280.55"),
            new BigDecimal("1140.56"),
            new BigDecimal("653.23"),
            new BigDecimal("847.49"),
            new BigDecimal("995.68")                

            };




    for(int i=0;i<valorbase.length;i++){

    BigDecimal desconto=new BigDecimal("0.985");

    //BigDecimal valor_a_descontar=valorbase[i].multiply(desconto);




    //valor_a_descontar=valor_a_descontar.setScale(2,RoundingMode.HALF_UP);
    //desconto=desconto.setScale(2,RoundingMode.HALF_UP);


    //BigDecimal valortotal=valorbase[i].subtract(valor_a_descontar);
    BigDecimal valortotal=valorbase[i].multiply(desconto);

    //valortotal.setScale(3,RoundingMode.HALF_UP);
    //valortotal.setScale(2,RoundingMode.HALF_EVEN);

    System.out.println("subtotal="+valortotal);

    if(valorbase[i].doubleValue()/1000>=1){
        valortotal=valortotal.setScale(8,RoundingMode.HALF_UP);
        valortotal=valortotal.setScale(7,RoundingMode.HALF_UP);
        valortotal=valortotal.setScale(6,RoundingMode.HALF_UP);
        valortotal=valortotal.setScale(5,RoundingMode.HALF_UP);
        valortotal=valortotal.setScale(4,RoundingMode.HALF_UP);
        valortotal=valortotal.setScale(3,RoundingMode.HALF_UP);
        valortotal=valortotal.setScale(2,RoundingMode.HALF_UP);
    }else{
        valortotal=valortotal.setScale(2,RoundingMode.HALF_UP);
    }       
    System.out.println("BASE="+valorbase[i]+" totalvalue="+valortotal);


    }

}
```

based on the Idea of Jay i make some modifications
the financial guys says: "well, we never can uP de discount to clients..we need some times round the due to up on cent"..

thanks for all!...

Comment: OK, so what are the return values from your function? Which values differ, and how?

Comment: If SQL's rounding gave you the answers you wanted, I guess that's cool. SQL doesn't offer any options on rounding rules, at least not any flavors of SQL that I'm familiar with, so I would think it would be harder that way. Whatever. If you're happy and your finance guy is happy, I'm sure we're all happy.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Are you sure that you are using the appropriate [RoundingMode](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/math/RoundingMode.html)?  RoundingMode 1 is `ROUND_DOWN` and RoundingMode 5 is `ROUND_HALF_DOWN`.  Perhaps you are supposed to use `ROUND_HALF_EVEN` (which is common in some financial scenarios)?

Also, the code would be clearer if you used these enum constants instead of the `RoundingMode.valueOf` method.

Comment: BASE=1077.70 - descount=16.17 totalvalue=1061.53 wrong with the table

Comment: ROUND_HALF_EVEN is also known as Banker's rounding.

Answer (score 1):

You always run into questions about the exact rounding rules with problems like this.

Like, do we round before or after the subtraction. Also, you might say that as a shortcut, a 1.5% discount is the same as saying that we charge 98.5% of regular price, so we should just be able to multiply the original price by 98.5% and not have to do an extra subtraction. Right?

Suppose the price is 667.00.

Method 1: 667.00 * .015 = 10.005, round up to 10.01. Then 667.00 - 10.01 = 656.99.

Method 2: 667.00 * .015 = 10.005. 667.00 - 10.005 = 656.995. Round up to 657.00. Different answer.

Method 3: 667.00 * .985 = 656.995, round up to 657.00.

Also, Roney mentioned that the table is wrong for 1077.70. It's also wrong for 1280.55.

Comment: thanks jay.. As might be expected soon had to give a result and had to do in sql, but I would settle in as we have other java applications with the same problem: (

Comment: JAY!!!! i tri it...and work....but one dont work fine
one value of table is missing '1280.55'
subtotal=1261.34175
BASE=1280.55 totalvalue=1261.34
all the values are correct! only this no...
someone in financial are wrong! 1261.34175 can't be rounded to 1261.35...by mathematical laws. im going to one reunion...the java WINS!!!! thanks very much!!!