# Problems with BigDecimal.ROUND_UP

Tags: java, bigdecimal, rounding

Why I am getting 184.84 as sell rate? Why is it acting like this in BigDecimal.ROUND_UP.
I checked with the BigDecimal.ROUND_HALF_EVEN. It works fine. But I wanna know why is it acting like this.

```
for(int i = 0; i < 50; i++){
    double  sellrate    = 184.83;
    BigDecimal sellRate = new BigDecimal(sellrate);
    sellRate    = sellRate.setScale(2,BigDecimal.ROUND_UP);
    System.out.println("sellRate : "+sellRate); 
}
```

Comment: so. how 184.83 become 184.84

Comment: Refer this link,http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2232480/the-java-bigdecimal-vs-the-financial-mans-the-1-cent-problem?rq=1

Comment: There are plenty of answers on why you're experiencing it due to the technicalities of the number, but it's also worth researching into monetary representation in programming - generally the use of Doubles or Floats is discouraged when representing financial values, due to to the problems involved with decimal arithmetic

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is why:

```
double sellrate = 184.83;
BigDecimal sellRate = new BigDecimal(sellrate);
System.out.println("sellRate: " + sellRate);
```

prints

```
sellRate: 184.830000000000012505552149377763271331787109375
```

This is explained in the [BigDecimal JavaDoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html#BigDecimal%28double%29):

> *The results of this constructor can be somewhat unpredictable. One might assume that writing new BigDecimal(0.1) in Java creates a
>   BigDecimal which is exactly equal to 0.1 (an unscaled value of 1, with
>   a scale of 1), but it is actually equal to
>   0.1000000000000000055511151231257827021181583404541015625. This is because 0.1 cannot be represented exactly as a double (or, for that
>   matter, as a binary fraction of any finite length). Thus, the value
>   that is being passed in to the constructor is not exactly equal to
>   0.1, appearances notwithstanding.*

Use the `String` constructor

```
BigDecimal sellRate = new BigDecimal("184.83");
```

if you want to get the exact value for your `BigDecimal`.

Comment: why is it taken extra values like this : 184.830000000000012505552149377763271331787109375

Comment: @NamalFernando: Added an explanation why.

Answer (score 1):

The [BigDecimal(double)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html#BigDecimal%28double%29) constructor is not very reliable, check the API javadoc. The preferred way to construct a BigDecimal is to use the [BigDecimal(String)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html#BigDecimal%28java.lang.String%29) constructor.

> **The results of this constructor can be somewhat unpredictable.** One
>   might assume that writing new BigDecimal(0.1) in Java creates a
>   BigDecimal which is exactly equal to 0.1 (an unscaled value of 1, with
>   a scale of 1), but it is actually equal to
>   0.1000000000000000055511151231257827021181583404541015625. This is because 0.1 cannot be represented exactly as a double (or, for that
>   matter, as a binary fraction of any finite length). Thus, the value
>   that is being passed in to the constructor is not exactly equal to
>   0.1, appearances notwithstanding.